# How to use ColumnDefinitions.Add correctly?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I copied an example about dock panel from "***WPF 4.5 Unleashed***" ch.5. In the example the dock is set to be in the right of the grid So when in the code behind `layer0.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column1CloneForLayer0);` called, a column with content `column1CloneForLayer0` will be created in the right side of the grid.
[image]

In my project I almost did the same thing, but when I call the function to add a column with some content, some empty space's created at the right side.. which is not as expected.So what's the right thing to do?
1.How to Add a column in the left side of a grid?

2.In the example the column was created yet why it's empty? Maybe Do i need to set the Z Index?

[image]

**Update**
I added something similar in the original example in the book and get wrong result. Below is the the source codes. I just added a `leftToolBox` in the left.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/61hm139j77kz9k1/AACKqhG5uXFkQgnt8fWi4NvNa?dl=0

**Update2**
Relevant codes: In this case I just add a stackpanel with button in the left side and and click to call `DocakPane(3)`, instead of giving the new column in the left, it creates column in the right.

```
public void DockPane(int paneNumber)
{
    if (paneNumber == 1)
    {
        pane1Button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        pane1PinImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pin.gif", UriKind.Relative));

        // Add the cloned column to layer 0:
        layer0.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column1CloneForLayer0);
        // Add the cloned column to layer 1, but only if pane 2 is docked:
        if (pane2Button.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed) layer1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column2CloneForLayer1);
    }
    else if (paneNumber == 2)
    {
        pane2Button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        pane2PinImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pin.gif", UriKind.Relative));

        // Add the cloned column to layer 0:
        layer0.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column2CloneForLayer0);
        // Add the cloned column to layer 1, but only if pane 1 is docked:
        if (pane1Button.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed) layer1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column2CloneForLayer1);
    }
    else
    {
        leftpane1Button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        pane3PinImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pin.gif", UriKind.Relative));
        layer0.ColumnDefinitions.Add(testcol);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you have to post some code, how you implemented it. If you don't we can only call our magic miracle machines to determine what went wrong

Comment: @Mark Question updated.

Comment: Please post the *relevant* code only here.

Comment: the code is quite hard-coded to be flexible for the desired function. Let me try to revise it for you. but before that your main concern is to know `how to add ColumnDefinitions.Add correctly?` or `how to achieve the docking like functionality?`

Comment: @pushpraj I know it's hard-coded.. Yet right now i don't know the smarter way to achieve the docking effect. The docking effect is achieved by hard coding `visibility`. I'd like to know how to correctly use that function .(Right now only the right-side panel button works)

Comment: So your main intention is to achieve the docking. one of the big problem with hard-coding is that it make difficult to make changes and it become more worse when it grows. I'll re-write your code for the same, so that it will help you understand the same and allow easily plug-in a new panel when required. in the meanwhile you can search internet, there are couple of libraries available for docking see if any of them match your exact needs, it is not always necessary to re-invent the wheel unless the intention is to learn from it.

Comment: @pushpraj Appreciate! the available libraries is not flexible enough as the look are fixed (same as visual studio) Going to sleep :}

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample project provided, here is a re-write of the same using MVVM and most of the problem related to hard-coding would are gone. It is not pure MVVM but it is mostly MVVM to get started with.

start by defining ViewModels

a class to represent the dock pane

```
class DockablePaneVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public DockablePaneVM(DockHostVM host)
    {
        Host = host;
    }

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    private bool _isPinned;
    public bool IsPinned
    {
        get { return _isPinned; }
        set
        {
            _isPinned = value;
            Host.PinModeChanged(this);
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsPinned");
        }
    }

    private object _content;
    public object Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set
        {
            _content = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Content");
        }
    }

    public DockHostVM Host { get; private set; }
    public Dock Dock { get; set; }
}
```

host for the dockpanes, I have used collectionview for simplifying the location

```
class DockHostVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public DockHostVM()
    {
        Panes = new ObservableCollection<DockablePaneVM>();
        LeftPanes = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = Panes }.View;
        RightPanes = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = Panes }.View;
        FlotingLeftPanes = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = Panes }.View;
        FlotingRightPanes = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = Panes }.View;

        LeftPanes.Filter = o => Filter(o, Dock.Left, true);
        RightPanes.Filter = o => Filter(o, Dock.Right, true);
        FlotingLeftPanes.Filter = o => Filter(o, Dock.Left, false);
        FlotingRightPanes.Filter = o => Filter(o, Dock.Right, false);
    }
    private bool Filter(object obj, Dock dock, bool isPinned)
    {
        DockablePaneVM vm = obj as DockablePaneVM;
        return vm.Dock == dock && vm.IsPinned == isPinned;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DockablePaneVM> Panes { get; set; }

    public ICollectionView LeftPanes { get; set; }
    public ICollectionView RightPanes { get; set; }

    public ICollectionView FlotingLeftPanes { get; set; }
    public ICollectionView FlotingRightPanes { get; set; }

    private object _content;

    public object Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set { _content = value; }
    }

    public void PinModeChanged(DockablePaneVM paneVM)
    {
        LeftPanes.Refresh();
        RightPanes.Refresh();
        FlotingLeftPanes.Refresh();
        FlotingRightPanes.Refresh();
    }

    //sample generator
    public static DockHostVM GetSample()
    {
        DockHostVM vm = new DockHostVM();
        vm.Panes.Add(new DockablePaneVM(vm) { Title = "Left Toolbox", Content = new ToolBoxVM() });
        vm.Panes.Add(new DockablePaneVM(vm) { Title = "Solution Explorer", Content = new SolutionExplorerVM(), Dock = Dock.Right });
        vm.Panes.Add(new DockablePaneVM(vm) { Title = "Toolbox", Content = new ToolBoxVM(), Dock = Dock.Right });
        return vm;
    }
}
```

then styles, to give provide the view for the classes

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:VisualStudioLikePanes">

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:DockablePaneVM}">
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Padding="8,4"
                       Text="{Binding Title}"
                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                       Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}"
                       Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionTextBrushKey}}" />
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsPinned}"
                          Grid.Column="1">
                <Image Name="pinImage"
                       Source="pinHorizontal.gif" />
            </ToggleButton>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPinned}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source"
                        TargetName="pinImage"
                        Value="pin.gif" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Header"
                Value="{Binding Title}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TabItem"
           x:Key="FloterItem"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TabControl">
        <Setter Property="l:TabControlHelper.IsLastItemSelected"
                Value="True" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                     Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TabControl"
           x:Key="AutoResizePane"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabControl}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Width"
                        Value="23" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:ToolBoxVM}">
        <ListBox Padding="10"
                 Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBoxItem>Button</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>CheckBox</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>ComboBox</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Label</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>ListBox</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:SolutionExplorerVM}">
        <TreeView Grid.Row="2">
            <TreeViewItem Header="My Solution" IsExpanded="True">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Project #1" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Project #2" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Project #3" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have also created some dummy classes to represent the toolbox and solution explorer

also a helper class to improve the usability of tab control which i have used to host the dockpanes

```
class TabControlHelper
{
    public static bool GetIsLastItemSelected(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsLastItemSelectedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsLastItemSelected(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsLastItemSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsLastItemSelected.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLastItemSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsLastItemSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(TabControlHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsLastItemSelected));

    private static void OnIsLastItemSelected(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl tc = d as TabControl;
        tc.Items.CurrentChanged += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            if (tc.SelectedIndex < 0 && tc.Items.Count > 0)
                tc.SelectedIndex = 0;
        };

    }
}
```

this will keep an item selected any time, in this project it will be used when a dock pane is pinned/unpinned

now the main window, note that I have bounded the dock Panes to 4 tab controls, left, right, left float & right float

```
<Window x:Class="VisualStudioLikePanes.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="500"
        Width="800"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:VisualStudioLikePanes">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetSample"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type l:DockHostVM}" />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="FILE" />
             ...
            <MenuItem Header="HELP" />
        </Menu>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True"
                   Grid.Row="1">

            <Border Width="23"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                    Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=LeftFloter}" />
            <Border Width="23"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=RightFloter}" />

            <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding LeftPanes}"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Left" />

            <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding RightPanes}"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Right" />

            <Grid Name="layer0">
                ... page content
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding FlotingLeftPanes}"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    TabStripPlacement="Left"
                    Style="{StaticResource AutoResizePane}"
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FloterItem}"
                    x:Name="LeftFloter" />

        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding FlotingRightPanes}"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    TabStripPlacement="Right"
                    Style="{StaticResource AutoResizePane}"
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FloterItem}"
                    x:Name="RightFloter" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

result is your expected behavior with MVVM approach, adding new panel is easy as `Panes.Add(new DockablePaneVM(vm) { Title = "Left Toolbox", Content = new ToolBoxVM() });` rest is handled.

[image: result]

**Demo**

download the working sample **[VisualStudioLikePanes.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2f5wPS0jKJPanNPcHBnXzd1dnM/view)**